# Do I need a South African transit visa to go to Swaziland?

Tags: transit, south-africa, swaziland

I am Rwandan and I want to go to Swaziland. Do I need a transit visa? I will only spend one hour in South Africa.

Comment: Presumably this is flying into SA and out again an hour later, not bus/car?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [IATA Travel Centre](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm):

> **TWOV (Transit Without Visa):**
>
> Passengers transiting through Cape Town (CPT), Durban (DUR),
> Johannesburg (JNB) or Lanseria (HLA) with a confirmed onward ticket
> for a flight to a third country. They must stay in the international
> transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next
> destination.

Assuming you're transiting in Johannesburg with a connecting flight to Swaziland, this implies that you shouldn't need a visa.

I took a few liberties when entering your details into the calculator since I don't know your travel document details, expiry date, etcetera, so I'd try it out yourself just in case.